# Get count of all associations to a model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model `A` as:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bp, class_name: "B", foreign_key: :bp_id
  belongs_to :cp, class_name: "B", foreign_key: :cp_id
end
```

I have a query where I am trying to get the size of all the associations to model `B` from model `A`.

I made it work by getting the count of all associations through `bp` and then `cp` and adding both up.

```
total_count = bp_size + cp_size
```

Is it possible to get the sum of all associations to `B model` from `A` in a single query?

My exact queries are as follows:

```
bp_size = E.where(f_id: g.joins(:f)).joins(bp: :s).size

cp_size = E.where(f_id: g.joins(:f)).joins(cp: :s).size
```

The above query goes through multiple levels of associations but then I join it through `bp` and `cp` to get the appropriate size. I want to avoid running that query twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no single idea about AR so-called “helpers”, but this is perfectly doable:

```
query = <<-SQL
  SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON (a.bp_id = b.id)) +
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON (a.cp_id = b.id))
SQL
A.connection.execute(query).to_a.first.first
```

Comment: It seems like that directly translates to `AR`. Can't believe I didn't try to create two joins. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic solution

```
def self.associations_counts_hash(model, association_types)
  associations = model.reflections.collect do |a, b| 
    b.plural_name if association_types.include?(b.macro)
  end.compact

  query = model.all.includes(associations)

  associations.map do |association| 
    [
      association, 
      query.map { |u| u.send(association).size }.sum
    ] 
  end.to_h
end

associations_counts_hash(User, [:belongs_to])
```

Couldn't work out a good solution to avoid a query for each association though.